# C# List Sort by Time in Reverse Chronological Order

Tags: c#, linq, datetime

<strike>I am saving Time field in my sql server database as nvarchar  in ("HH:mm") format.</strike>

Upon the suggestion of EVERYONE. I now saved the time in my sql server database in DateTime format. Though I won't be needing the date part, I will use this property so that I can achieve the effect Im trying to do.
Now what I want to do is get a list of row in reverse chronological order based on the current time of execution. For example if my table looks like this:

```
tblFavoriteTime
ID     Time       Post
1     05:00 AM    Something..
2     09:00 AM    Another..
3     12:00 PM    Hello..
4     01:00 PM    Its 8 am..
```

When I visit the site at 12:00PM, I need the list of time in reverse chronological order. So 12:00PM will be at the top of the list, `12:00PM -> 11:00AM -> 10:00AM -> .... 1:00AM -> 12:00AM -> 01:00PM -> 02:00PM -> ..... 11:00PM` Using the data above, I should get:

```
ID     Time         Post
3     12:00 PM      Hello...
2     09:00 AM      Another..
1     05:00 AM      Something..
4     01:00 PM      Its 1 pm..
```

Is there a way to do this using `LinQ .OrderBy()` or something like this:

```
var mylist = _repository.GetAll().ToList()
            .OrderBy(x => x.TimeStamp.TimeOfDay() .......); 
            //as I explained, Im only getting the time of day though its a datetime object, date part wont matter..
```

Please help!

Comment: how is 13:00 at last after sorting?

Comment: Why you store a [time](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb677243.aspx) as nvarchar?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad lets say you have a clock, when you look at it at 12:00AM, imagine the clock going counter clockwise, `12AM -> 11AM -> ... -> 1AM -> 12PM - 1PM`

Comment: This should just be `FavoriteTimes.OrderByDescending(x => x.Time)`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I saved it as nvarchar because the date part does not matter in my program. And c# does not really have a proper equivalent type for Time(3) sql server, it convert it as Timespan and that is not really what I need. So what I do is save it as nvarchar then when I need it, convert it to datetime format in c#. I hope you get it.

Comment: @TimSchmelter same principle when you save a time format as int(numberOfTicks)

Comment: @super-user: but it is a `TimeSpan` isn't it? The time-span from midnight to this time. That's the most appropriate type in the framework for a time.

Comment: @super-user one bad practice doesn't justify another bad practice. Use the *proper* type to store time values. Ticks for example guarantee problems since they have no timezone, no idea of daylight saving, have an extremely limited range (escpecially if it's int), no possibility of proper ordering or sorting (due to the lack of tz offsets).

Comment: Doesn't `OrderByDescending(p => p.Time)` do the job?

Comment: @Enigmativity Can I set a specific field as the start point of the OrderByDescending? Like I want to get 10:00 as top of the list and get the rest of the rows in descending order from 10:00

Comment: Descending from 10:00? What results would that yield? If you had times after and before 10:00 what you expect to see?

Comment: @mig `12:00PM -> 11:00AM -> 10:00AM -> .... 1:00AM -> 12:00AM -> 01:00PM -> 02:00PM -> ..... 11:00PM`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
var times = new [] { "10:30", "22:40", "12:00", "10:00", "13:00", "08:00", };

var output = times.OrderByDescending(x => (x.CompareTo("10:00") <= 0 ? "Z" : "") + x);
```

I get the following:

```
10:00 
08:00 
22:40 
13:00 
12:00 
10:30
```

---

Try this for `DateTime` fields.

```
var times =
    new [] { "10:30", "22:40", "12:00", "10:00", "13:00", "08:00", }
        .Select(x => DateTime.Parse(x));

var output = times.OrderByDescending(x => (x.TimeOfDay.TotalHours <= 10 ? 24.0 : 0.0) + x.TimeOfDay.TotalHours);
```

I get the same result as above.

Comment: Yes im trying to do that kind of output. But what should I reference to use CompareTo(), im getting red squiggly lines when calling it and my vs2013 cannot auto resolve it

Comment: How can I use this if I have an array of DateTime objects? I am trying to follow people's suggestion in the comment section to use proper DateTime property..

Comment: Thanks alot. Works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

If you are "*stuck*" with a `nvarchar`, then you could parse to a TimeSpan first, e.g.

```
var times = new [] { "10:30", "22:40", "12:00", "10:00", "13:00", "08:00", };
var output = times.OrderByDescending(x => TimeSpan.Parse(x));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
TimeSpan now = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay; //site visit time

var query = rows.ToList()
  .OrderBy(x => x.TimeStamp.TimeOfDay <= now ? 1 : 2)
  .ThenByDescending(x => x.TimeStamp.TimeOfDay);
```